# C++ source code formatter

Tags: gratis, c++, code-beautification

I am coding a tool to parse C++ code. I don't want to end up coding half of a compiler. Even though I am aware of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), that is too much for my purposes.

I was hand-parsing, but have come up against one too many coding styles.

I seek a tool which will parse C++ code, with only one important factor :

It must be able to put the entire function declaration on a single line.

So, things like

```
unsigned
int
myclass::
myfunc
(int x;
int y)
{
}
```

and all of its *many* variations, should become

```
unsigned int myclass::myfunc(int x; int y)
{
}
```

That’s all that I need for this particular project - the ability to find each function in a file and get it's return type.

Nice if it's Linux, but I can live with Windows.

GUI would be nice, with preview being a bonus.

Batch mode would be nice, including the ability to recursively process a given directory.

But none of those *nice* are mandatory, only the `single line for the function declaration requirement is`.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Community Edition which is free. It support C++ and the code formatting is very good and also is customizable to a certain degree to fit your liking.

Comment: But, does it support my **single** requirement?

Comment: Partially. Replace all `\n` by `[space]`, CTRL+A, CTRL+K then CTRL+F to format, then replace all `{` by `\n{` and replace all `}` by `\n}` this can be scripted to go through all files.

Comment: Community Edition also have a Web version running of a webpage so compatible with virtually any operating systems

Comment: @Franck, do you have a URL for that?

Comment: [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx) the main web page. Right bottom corner you can signup for 5 free basic license. all code saved with Git so there is built in source control

Comment: "I seek a tool which will parse C++ code, with only one important factor : It must be able to put the entire function declaration on a single line."  This is not a parser.  Maybe you are looking for a C++ parser that you can use to build a prettyprinter.  But that's not what your title says.  Then you say, "you need to find each function and get its return type"  So what it is you want?   If you actually want the return type, you'll need preprocessing and symbol tables too. This SR request is very badly written.

Comment: @Mawg:  ... So what  do you mean, "you want the return type"?  You want just the string of characters used to declare the type, or something deeper?  If the function header is "int foo(...)" then the return type is obviously "int".  What is the return type for "T foo(...)"; is it "T", or the typedef behind T?  How about "A:B:C:T foo(...)"?  What if the return type is template invocation?  A macro call?  Involves a prepreprocessor conditional?

Comment: Wow! That's a tough question. There is no templating in our code, so a simple return type would do. But that is a very good point. It looks like I might have to end up coding half of a compiler :-(

Comment: @Mawg: You didn't answer the question about what you do you want for the return type.  It might help if you told us what you were going to do with the result, too.  Without a response, it is not possible for the rest of us to judge the utility of any answers (e.g., "astyle" or gnu indent).

Comment: I have been in a new job for some time now, so the question is only of historical inetrest.  IIRC, I wanted to parse code and generate code stubs for use in unit testing. For typed functions, I wanted to add a return statement, to keep the comiler happy. Howver, I never go that far, as I coudl find a parser which could handle the code

Answer (score 1):

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

aStyle - no competition.  I've been using this for a while now as I tend to write functions in notepad++ on my way to work and then beautify it with this before inclusion in projects - it really does a great job in my opinion.

Comment: does it support my **single** requirement? If so, how?

Comment: Six months and no evidence this supports OP's requirement.  Downvoting as "not a high quality answer".

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Indent](//gnu.org/software/indent) can handle this:

```
indent b.c
```

Input:

```
unsigned
int
myfunc
(int x;
int y)
{
}
```

Output:

```
unsigned int myfunc (int x; int y)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to end up coding half of a compiler

It's not that complicated for the feature you're requesting. Here is a [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) script to start you off.

The arrays `keywords_nospace` and `keywords_space` contain the words/characters at the end of the lines you want to combine. The first is for combining without spaces, and the second appends spaces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, "<", $ARGV[0]) or die "Can't open file: $!";
open(my $out, ">", "restructured_$ARGV[0]");

my $word;
my @keywords_nospace = ("::","myfunc");
my @keywords_space = ("unsigned","int",";");

while (<$in>) {
   for $word (@keywords_nospace) {chomp if (/\Q$word\E$/i);} # removes trailing spaces and newline
   for $word (@keywords_space)
     {
       if (/\Q$word\E$/i)
     {
       chomp; # Removes trailing spaces and newline
       $_ = "$_ "; # Add a space at the end of the line
     }
     }
  print $out $_;
}
```

You can add as many keywords as you like. Save in a `.pl` file, and run in the command line using:

```
perl script_name.pl input.cpp
```

This should create a new file in the directory called `restructured_input.cpp`. I've tested it on your example function and got the desired output.

Comment: Just because this "works" on his specific example doesn't make this general.  You can't "reformat" an *arbitrary* piece of C++ code without having a full C++ parser.  Macros, preprocessor conditionals, types, template specifications (esp. ">>"), lambda declarations, nesting, you name it are all going to complicate what is on the "function header line" far beyond what this script (or any script that doesn't essentially parse) can do.

Comment: @IraBaxter It's not intended to be *general*. I understand that actual programs are more complex than that, but the OP asked for a very specific requirement and provided a very simple example. The answer matches those, and it only serves the purpose to show how it can be done for such simple cases. If the OP needs more requirements, it's up to him to specify them in the question as per the rules of this site.

Comment: He said *I seek a tool which will parse C++ code*.   I think it reasonable to assume he wanted to process arbitrary C++ code, not just the example.